# Can we create a Flutter based SDK and then utilized in a different Native app project

Tags: android, ios, flutter, ionic-framework, sdk

We have a problem to address. We want to transform out ionic based app to an Android SDK and want to use in a separate Native project later on. Which I found out to be not possible or extremely hard.

While figuring out if same can be done on Flutter, I found out that SDK or aar file can be created for a flutter module but can only be used in flutter created android project with the flutter app code.

I want this flutter lib based android project to be a library and export to another project.
Can this be done as of now?
How good is it to create SDKs from crossplatform language to use in native both Android and iOS.